# How to prepend angular directives with "data-"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What do I have to do to prepend angular directives like `ng-app` wit `"data-"` to guarantee my HTML successfully validates?

Is there some setting somewhere I have to change?

Edit:

My confusion stems from the fact that `ng-*` seems like such a poor naming system when, with five more characters you could have a solution that is totally valid HTML. I expected that if the `data-*` prepending method was intrinsically supported it would be the desired method of naming directives.

Comment: No. It works out of the box. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! sorry I didn't realise this - I've just started learning angular. I googled it for a while but everyone just recommends you use this prepending method and nobody actually says how (that it works out of the box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already handled by AngularJS, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives:

> The following forms are all equivalent and match the `ngBind` directive:
>
> ```
> <span ng-bind="name"></span>
> <span ng:bind="name"></span>
> <span ng_bind="name"></span>
> <span data-ng-bind="name"></span>
> <span x-ng-bind="name"></span>
> ```

Comment: thanks for this! It seems to me as though data-ng-bind is the best solution for naming directives. I don't understand why the "x-" prefix is accepted - that is intended to be reserved for user agents isn't it? And "ng-*" isn't valid HTML. My confusion derives from the fact that such a sloppy directive naming system seems to be the desired one. Or are there reasons that make not prepending with "data-" better?

Comment: @JamesStott [According to Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/html-validation-does-it-matter/), does HTML Validation really matter? Yes. No. Maybe. `:)`

Comment: I can't `@` your name for some reason. I guess Jeff Atwood makes some okay-ish points. But just because other code isn't validated doesn't mean that no code should be validated. I think standardised practises are always good - and it may not seem like so to a professional who understands how this work at the most fundamental level but to someone learning something new, best practises and compliance with web standards makes learning easier otherwise you end up with multiple ways of doing things (all producing the same result) yet it's hard to see how they relate.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any settings nor configs to do. You can out of the box write